# How to authenticate additional field beside username and password?

Tags: php, symfony

Standard authentication requires user to provide username and the password. How to add another field to that process? The field is part of the User entity.

Basically I want to get user both by username and that field, then simply authenticate him against the password.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a great potential use of the relatively new [Symfony Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) component.

Some of the example code would be very easy to extend (in the `getCredentials()` & `checkCredentials()` methods) to also require additional information match.